# MVC Generating CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv

I'm very new to MVC and I've been trying to find a way to save my data as a CSV file so that I may send it as email attachment once compiled. But I'm struggling to workout how I can pass the data from my view to this new file.

Right now, my view is gathering the information like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SampleMethod", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>1. @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { placeholder = "Enter First Name" }) </p>
    <p>2. @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { placeholder = "Enter Last Name" }) </p>
}
```

This is gathered via a webform and I can get this information to display on a separate webpage. I'm doing this in the following method in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SampleMethod(TestModel newTest)
{
   return View("Completed", newTest);
}
```

But now I'm really stuck in how I can put my information (first and last name) into a CSV file as I'm struggling to understand where and how I should pass my data to.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a few things, like what you want to call the CSV file you generate and where you want to put it.
In essence though you need to create a text file and write a string to it with commas separating the first and last names.
Start by looking at this kind of thing for the file creation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx

Then it is just a case of building the string to write to it, using fairly standard string handling functions.